# What off-the-shelf component can I use to store a number with arbitrary precision in the integer part and limited precision in the fractional part?

Tags: c++, arbitrary-precision

I am wondering about what off-the-shelf component I can use to keep a limited decimal digits precision in the fractional part and arbitrary precision in the integer part, without implementing it myself?

I can see boost has similar concepts:

- `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` is integer with arbitrary precision.
- `boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50` has 50 decimal digits precision total.

A non-optimal approach is to implement it, as opposed to using a ready component, such as to use `cpp_int` and keep values multiplied by 10**k; use `cpp_rational` for arbitrary precision rational numbers; or keep the value in both a `cpp_int` and `cpp_dec_float_50` for the integer and fractional parts respectively.

Is there a readily available library component?

Comment: Not sure if you are asking a question or not.  SO is not an ideas feedback site as you will be asking for an opinion.

Comment: Reusability and making the right choice in the use of building blocks is fundamental to good software engineering. I believe a question about the available modules is as valid as a question about unclear API input requirements or about an algorithm.

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk I get the premise of the question but it was a bit all over the place. See if that edit is still what you were thinking, because it is much more clear now.

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk Maybe also edit the question and add why you think your approach is non-optimal.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [GMP](https://gmplib.org)?

Comment: Possible, but so far I can't find suitable types/functions in their documentation.

Comment: Sorry, library requests are off-topic.

Comment: Library requests are part of a wider class of questions, i.e., questions on types/functions to do a particular thing. This includes "standard library requests", like how to make a constant-sized vector? how to find the first value in a set above a threshold? how to setup a TCP connection? Those questions aren't treated as "off-topic" as they shouldn't be, but it's not them being about the standard library that they shouldn't be closed, but because careful component selection is a crucial part of software engineering.

Comment: _"...Is there a readily available library component?..."_ looks like a library request to me.  If this type of question belongs on SO should really be discussed on meta.